# Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:7443

Tags: android-emulator, localhost, xmpp, openfire, smack

Hi i am using openfire as my im server to my mobile app client, I have added the Httpfileupload plugin to openfire and enabled the http bind settings, when I try to upload a file it shows me this error Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:7443 ,
and the servers send me this XML message `<get url="https://localhost:7443/httpfileupload/45726202-5e69-4b5c-a533-00d82f6d1121/4add76e7f15b6b4f.png"/>`
I’ve tried to access this uri but it doesn’t work
please help me with this issues
i am using the latest smack version and the latest openfire version also

Comment: btw i am using android emulator

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have set up Openfire using the value 'localhost' as its XMPP domain and/or fully qualified domain name for the server that is running Openfire. This is a recipe for disaster. Openfire is broadcasting the address of the content that is managed by its HTTP File Upload plugin, and uses the value that was configured, 'localhost'. Clients, which typically run on different machines, will try to connect to this host. As they're instructed to connect to 'localhost', they'll never be able to reach Openfire.

My advise is to setup Openfire again, and use proper, network-reachable addresses for values of the XMPP domain name and FQDN (these are asked for in the second page of the setup wizard, if memory serves).